# How to read custom TIFF tags (w/o TIFFFieldInfo)

Tags: c++, c, tiff, libtiff

I'm trying to read a custom tag in a tiff file.

There are few instruction about this topic, but AFAIK they are using an interface (struct) called TIFFFieldInfo. I've read the [documentation](http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/addingtags.html) already, and again TIFFFieldInfo showed up.
I could go with it, but they ([the library](https://code.google.com/p/openjpeg/source/browse/trunk/libs/libtiff/tiffio.h?r=697)) are saying, that interface is OBSOLETED. Could you suggest me reasonable alternatives?
Or have I just misreaded the header file?

Comment: If you can't find any uptodate library, writing a TIFF info reader from scratch isn't that hard; the docs are pretty straightforward. (I made one years ago; I'll see if I can find the source, but it's probably rather out of date by now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution. 
The manual ([TIFFGetField(3tiff)](http://web.mit.edu/fwtools_v1.1.2/man/man3/TIFFGetField.3tiff)) says all we need. See the AUTOREGISTERED TAGS session. The following is copy-pasted one.

> AUTOREGISTERED TAGS If you can't find the tag in the table above  that
>   means  this  is  an unsupported  tag  and  is  not  directly 
>   supported  by  libtiff(3TIFF) library. You will still be able to read
>   it's value if you know the data type  of that tag. For example, if you
>   want to read the LONG value from the tag 33424 and ASCII string from
>   the tag 36867 you can use the following code:
>
> ```
> uint32  count;
> void    *data;
>
> TIFFGetField(tiff, 33424, &count, &data);
> printf("Tag %d: %d, count %d0", 33424, *(uint32 *)data, count);
> TIFFGetField(tiff, 36867, &count, &data);
> printf("Tag %d: %s, count %d0", 36867, (char *)data, count);
> ```

For example, I need to read a tag which is double, so I used the following code (but I didn't check IT):

```
tiff *tif = TIFFOpen("ex_file.tif", "rc");   // read tif
static ttag_t const TIFFTAG_SOMETAG = 34362; // some custom tag
if(tif != nullptr) // if the file is open
{
    uint count; // get count
    double *data; // get data
    if(TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_SOMETAG, &count, &data) == 1) // read tag
        throw std::logic_error("the tag does not exist.");

    // print the values (caution: count is in bytes)
    for(int index = 0; index < count / sizeof(double); ++index)
        std::cout << data[index];
    TIFFClose(tif); // close the file
}
else
    throw std::runtime_error("cannot open the file");
```